# Generating video frames and assembling them in Java?

Tags: java, video

I need to develop an application that can perform the following functions:

- Read in a set of data
- Generate frames and display them on-screen (probably using `Graphics2D`)

I believe I can easily achieve the above.
However, if the correct command-line flag is passed in, I want to be able to, instead of rendering the frames to the screen, **render to a video file**. (Container/codec is unimportant)

What is a way to achieve this?

Preferably avoiding having an intermediate directory full of image files.
Perhaps there is some way to open an `ffmpeg` process and feed in the frames (via stdin?) and have it do the job?